# SpriteKit didBeginContact function not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I am trying to get collision working in my SpriteKit game using the didBeginContact function.

My problem is that the function is just not getting called at all when the ball bounces off of the bricks. This is how I have set them both up:

```
static const uint32_t blockCollisionCheck = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t ballCollisionCheck = 0x1 << 1;
```

Ball:

```
SKShapeNode *ball = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

CGMutablePathRef drawPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(drawPath, NULL, 0, 0, _ballRadius, 0, M_PI * 2, YES);
ball.path = drawPath;
CGPathRelease(drawPath);

ball.fillColor = [SKColor greenColor];

ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 150);
ball.name = @"ball";


ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:_ballRadius];
ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCollisionCheck;
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = blockCollisionCheck;
[self addChild:ball];
```

Bricks:

```
SKSpriteNode *block = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(_blockWidth, _blockHeight)];
block.name = @"block";
block.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
block.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:block.size];
block.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
block.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
block.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
block.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blockCollisionCheck;
block.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCollisionCheck;
[self addChild:block];
```

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong with this, as I have the category bit masks correct I think? Also both of the sprites are Dynamic, which is another problem I read it could have been.

It's not that the contents of my didBeginContact function is not working, it's just never getting there as evidenced from a lack of NSLog message and breakpoints not being reached.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you say, the didBeginContact method is not being called at all, I suspect you did not add the `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;` into your GameScene init method.

Comment: Ah of course, the one thing I did not even think about. Still pretty novice at all this Objective C magic, so I keep forgetting about setting delegates like that. Thank you for your help!